# Upgrading from Django1.3 to 1.8 - Are migrations mandatory?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

My application has been on production for 3 years and the DB model is stable. It seems to me that adding migrations support is more pain that it is worth.
Is it possible/desirable to upgrade without migrations support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good old `syncdb` command is still there. If all you need is to add/drop tables(models), you can continue to use that. The new migration support doesn't make any difference to you if you don't create any migrations (with `makemigration` and `migrate` commands).

That said, enabling migration is still recommended. You never know when your schema will change, even for a stable DB model. If you don't like Django's builtin migration solution, try `south`, which was the de facto standard, and have been proven solid.

Comment: Many thanks. Enabling migrations for my application would be a second step then, after getting the application to work with 1.8. The main purpose of the migration is to use performance and security improvements that the new version brings.